# list of checkbox that will act like a list of radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, php

i have 4 list of checkboxes, now i want to happen is that when one is already checked, the other checkboxes will be disabled.

im trying to find answers for a couple of hours now and i cant find any solutions for my problem.

here is my code:

```
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
<input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
<input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
<input id="check4" type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>





</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just use radio buttons?

Comment: the reason why is that each of that checkbox has sub radio buttons

Comment: its still ok... Just open those sub radio buttons on click...

Comment: the problem of the radio button is that i cant deselect it.

Comment: ok, i get your problem

Comment: you can use .checked = false

Comment: how? its like a radio button but the advantage of the checkbox is that

Comment: If the only reason not to use radio buttons is because it can't be de-selected, being able to de-select a radio button is probably a lot easier than adding radio button behavior to a list of checkboxes.  Just add a click handler to the radio buttons which looks to see if it's checked and, if it is, uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

Using this html code:

```
<form id="foo">
    <input id="check1" type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
    <input id="check2" type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
    <input id="check3" type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
    <input id="check4" type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="call(this)"/>
</form>
```

And this javascript code:

```
function call(obj){
    nCheckBoxes = 4;
    //unchecks all the checkboxes 
    for(i=1;i<=nCheckBoxes;i++){
         document.getElementById("check"+i).checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;
    //other functions here
}
```

Comment: radio buttons cannot be deselect when selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone but something like this should work if you are using jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you need:

```
    function call(obj) {

        var temp = obj.checked
            i = 1;

        for (; i <= 4; i++) {
            document.getElementById("check" + i).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("check" + i).disabled = temp ? "disabled" : "";
        }

        obj.checked = temp;
        obj.disabled = "";

    }
```

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshcp/Us29B/)